# Using HTML drop down boxes to sort through custom fields in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, sorting, drop-down-menu, field

I have a website (located [here](http://enoda.co.uk/)) and I would like to do something to improve the way people search and view different reviews.

I have thought about introducing a way to search through posts based on rating. I currently have one category which has custom field with the field title "Rating". Each value in the custom field is an integer from 1 to 5.

Here's the test category (http://enoda.co.uk/category/ipad-2/ipad-reviews/ipad-utilities/)

I was wanting to know how I would go about introducing a drop down menu somewhere above the posts in the category with star ratings from 1 up to 5. Further, I would like it to take users to reviews with that rating.

Any help would be great,
Best regards,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

Jack,

This is a somewhat complex issue as there are a number of areas within your WP installation that you need address to solve your problem. I'll point you in the right direction, but I don't anticipate that this will be the full answer for you.

First of all, the dropdown. Since you know that you want nothing more that a dropdown that displays choice of rating, you can easily hard code this. Since it is in a custom field, controlled by you, that only you/your colleagues set, you will know what is in that field and can feel safe hard coding this. Alternatively, I would have set up rating as a custom taxonomy with the terms '1 Star', '2 Stars', etc. and then you could build your drop down dynamically from this taxonomy. But, since it's in a custom field, I would just use something like this:

```
<form action="rating-search.php" method="GET">
    <select name="rating-search" id="rating-search">
        <option value="1">1 Star</option>
        <option value="2">2 Stars</option>
        <option value="3">3 Stars</option>
        <option value="4">4 Stars</option>
        <option value="5">5 Stars</option>
    </select>
    <input id="rating-search-submit" name="rating-search-submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Now, I'll assume that you can handle the submission of this data. On the page that receives this data (you can accomplish this with a template page), you will need to modify the wp_query to search only for posts that have a meta value of rating = {input value}. You will need code similar to:

```
$query = new WP_Query();
$query->query(
    array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'rating', // Insert the name of the meta key here
                'value' => $_POST['rating-search'], // This is the rating you are matching
                'compare' => '=',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            )
        )
    )
);

if($query->have_posts())
{
    while($query->have_posts())
    {
        $query->the_post();
        global $post;

        //Do normal loop business here
    }
}
```

That query will help you search for posts that have the custom field set to the desired value. Note that the `meta_query` parameter only works for WP 3.1 and higher. It's a super powerful feature and worth updating to 3.1 alone. More about what you can do with the WP_Query class can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query.

I know you can't just copy and paste this code to get what you want, but I hope this gives you some ideas of what you can do to get closer to your desired result. Good luck!

Comment: Cheers for the reply. By any chance would you also know how I could implement this on **each** category. I'm unsure which page I would put it on for it to be displayed on each category page — I'm unsure if all templates have a certain category file.

Comment: You want to be able to do this search for each category? If so, you can add `'cat' => '{category id}'`, substituting the actual numerical category id for {category id}, to the parent array sent to `$query->query`.

Comment: I've tried doing everything you'd said and with my own and others' help but to no avail. Could you perhaps come up with a quick solution which is closer to getting the actual final modification? It seems to be logical but implementing it is hard.

Comment: Jack...I cannot do that because this problem is not specific enough for me to know what you need done. I've been trying to lead you an answer. I'd be happy to look at some code that you put in pastebin in order to work with you toward the solution.